# Unable to run parallel tests with Selenium Grid(Appium) in Android?

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I want to execute test script on multiple devices(Android). when i run my java class with JUnit i am able to execute in only one device. How to execute in multiple devices at a time.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

TestNG.xml file

```
<suite name="Default suite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
<test name="Nexus">
<Parameters>
<parameter name="platform" value="Nexus"/>
<parameter name="browsername" value="Android"/>
 <parameter name="udid"  value="xyz" />
<parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"/>
</Parameters>
<classes>
<class name="AppiumTest">
<methods>
<include name="Test1"/>
<include name="Test2"/>
<include name="Test3"/>
</methods>
</class>
</classes>
</test>
<test name="Moto E">
<Parameters>
<parameter name="platform" value="Moto E"/>
<parameter name="browsername" value="Android"/>
<parameter name="udid"  value="abc" />
<parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://0.0.0.0:4726/wd/hub"/>
</Parameters>
<classes>
<class name="AppiumTest">
<methods>
<include name="Test1"/>
<include name="Test2"/>
<include name="Test3"/>
</methods>
</class>
</classes></suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just launch another test after the first is launched. Of course each test must be pointed to different device.

Comment: If you manually launch tests then parallel testing is impossible at all by the definition. But if you will automate launch it will work parallel (e.g. in Jenkins).

Comment: By using TestNG whether parallel test will be possible or not ?

Comment: I do not use TestNG. You need to look up on its documentation. But the other answer states that you can. You must investigate yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If you use testNG instead of JUnit you can create a test suite with a testng.xml file that should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Nexus 7">
    <parameter name="udid"  value="XXXX" />
    <classes>
      <class name="testNG.TestOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="HTC desrire">
    <parameter name="udid"  value="XXXX" />
    <classes>
      <class name="testNG.TestOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Stating *parallel tests* and a *thread-count of 2* allows two tests to be completed on seperate devices in parallel.

All you need to do from here is configure Selenium Grid nodes with capabilities of each device and in your tests script use the *udid* parameter passed in through the testng.xml.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my TestNG.xml file..can you please check it out an d let me know if i wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the concept shown in the below thread.It is using grid concept in selenium to start two appium sessions in parallel.By this we can run our scripts parallely on two android devices.

https://discuss.appium.io/t/connecting-appium-server-to-selenium-grid-for-android/804/10